# R separating values between columns

Tags: r

I've got a problem with my data.

My problem is the following. I've got a column with values as below: 
`data <- c(1,2,4,6,8,13,14,16)`

In new data frame I want to write down in separate columns the values until the difference between the first and each subsequent is less than 10 (for ex. 2-1<10, 8-1<10 but 13-1>10 -> so 13 is the first value in second column). 
Values can not be repeated in different columns.
Example output below:

```
1   13
2   14
4   16
6    0
8    0
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: How do you want to deal with unbalanced columns like you have in your example? Use `NA`? Something else?

Comment: I created data.frame with '0

Comment: What do you mean by "values of which the difference is less than 10"?

Comment: aa sorry, I see that I did not specify properly. I'll correct

Comment: Do you mean like `split(data, c(data[1], data[-1] - data[1]) > 10)`?

Comment: Are you trying `data[data - data[1] >  10]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. (Edited to reflect new problem description)

```
data <- c(1,2,4,6,8,13,14,16)

D2 <- split(data, (data - data[1]) %/% 10)

max_length <- max(lengths(D2))

D2 <- lapply(D2,
       function(d, m) c(d, rep(0, m - length(d))),
       max_length) 
(D2 <- as.data.frame(D2))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but reading the updated description, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Also, there's the new `lengths` function in base R instead of your `vapply` approach.

Comment: No, I agree with you.  I missed the update before posting my answer.  This looks like the right answer, but logic needed for getting there.  I'll try to salvage.  And thanks for the `lengths` tip.  I missed that update. (okay, that was easier to salvage than I expected)

Comment: I tested the method from Benjamin and it works well :)

Comment: You could also try `out <- data.frame(lapply(D2, `length<-`, max_length))` and then do `out <- replace(out, is.na(out), 0)`.